# System.invalidOperationException with thread that downloads from FTP

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, ftp

I am trying to download a chat.txt file from my ftp server so it updates fast instead of with a timer because the form is lagging with a timer. but now i get the error:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

and my code is:

```
Private Sub RefreshChat()
    Dim client As New Net.WebClient
    client.Credentials = New Net.NetworkCredential("username", "pass")
    Do
        Try
            Dim ChatInfo = client.DownloadString("ftp://ftphost/Users/" + Me.Text + "/" + Me.Text + TextBox3.Text + "Chat.txt")
            TextBox1.Text = Decrypt(ChatInfo)
        Catch

        End Try
    Loop
End Sub
```

this is the full error i get:

A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Comment: Which line in the code you posted causes the exception?  Please post a stack trace.  Where is the `RefreshChat` method called?  You need to show more code.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're getting the exception around the "TextBox1.text" line? Check out what type the Decrypt function returns and if it is a string, and what is ChatInfo exactly?

Comment: Chat info is the data that i download from the FTP server. But you cant read the text because you have to decrypt it first and it returns a readable string.

Comment: And it gives an error exactly after the textbox1.text = Decrypt(Chatinfo) line

Comment: Is this the Main thread or thread that you created ?

Comment: No but i now now that you can fix it by using checkcrossthread = false ...